# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck at installing screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have an Asus ROG - G551V with Windows 10 installed.

I am trying to dual boot it with Ubuntu 16.04 but it is always stucks at booting. (At the screen where it shows you 'Ubuntu' together with the 5 dots.)

I've been trying to both install it from USB and DVD, but I always end up at the same screen.
I can't even select 'Try Ubuntu...' option.

What can I do?

Comment: @DavidFoerster how? He said he stuck at the 5 dots screen! not blank screen

Comment: @AnwarShah: You're right but in this case it's all the same though. The purple loading screen rendered by Plymouth just hides the usually grey on black kernel log. If the boot process fails or stalls during that stage it doesn't matter if Plymouth is running or not (unless the issue is related to Plymouth itself incidentally but usually it's some hardware driver or storage configuration issue).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I'm convinced and voted to close